# how to describe table topology in UML?

Tags: uml

I have 3 tables A(A1,A2,A3), B and C. (A1-A3 is attribute of table A). A1 is a mux. If A1 is 1, A2 will index table B, and if A1 is 0, A3 will index table C.

Can we describe this topology in UML? If not, what other tool I can use to describe the topology?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [programmers.se]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event driven process chain ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_process_chain ) for this. This diagram is made for modeling processes. Otherwise you can have a look at the state diagram ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram_(UML) ), but I don't think, that this is what you need. The event driven process chain should totally fit your needs.

Comment: It's not database. It's like a programing sequence. When we get an entry of table A, we look at field A1/A2/A3 of this entry. If A1 is 1, we will use A2 as index to find the corresponding entry in table B. If A1 is 0, we will use A3 as index to find the entry in table C. We have a lot of tables. So I want to find a good way to describe it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a tool to generate the event driven process chain? And can the generated file be used for further processing? (e.g..use a script to process the generated file)

Comment: Try Microsoft VISIO for example (expensive). Or yEd (free and very smart).

http://www.yworks.com/de/products_yed_about.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a Generalization-Specialization relation, in a Class Diagram, it is known as an "IS-A" relationship in an Entity-Relation model.

```
..............................................
............................+------------+....
........................+---+     B      |....
........................|...+------------+....
..................../|..|.....................
..+------------+.../.|..|...+------------+....
..|     A      +--<..+--+---+     C      |....
..+------------+...\.|..|...+------------+....
....................\|..|.....................
........................|...+------------+....
........................+---+     D      |....
............................+------------+....
..............................................
```

Note, that I didn't put the fields in the diagram, because the "if A1 is 1 use the table B ..." cannot be described directly in an U.M.L. diagram. I'll put a round around, in a later diagram.

This may be modeled in a diagram. The tables may be created in a database. But, the access to the secondary tables, is usually implemented (coded) by a program. I think, some databases support it, without programming.

Before, showing a small code, the same diagram with fields, could be:

```
..................................................
..........................{0,1}.+------------+....
........................+-------+     B      |....
........................|.......+------------+....
........................|.......| [+] A2     |....
........................|.......+------------+....
........................|.......|    ...     |....
........................|.......+------------+....
........................|.........................
........................|.........................
................1.../|..|.........................
..+------------+.../.|..|.{0,1}.+------------+....
..|     A      +--<..+--+-------+     C      |....
..+------------+...\.|..|.......+------------+....
..| [+] A1     |....\|..|.......| [+] A3     |....
..| [+] A2     |........|.......+------------+....
..| [+] A3     |........|.......|    ...     |....
..| [+] A4     |........|.......+------------+....
..+------------+........|.........................
..|    ...     |........|.........................
..+-------+----+........|.........................
..........|.............|.{0,1}.+------------+....
..........|.............+-------+     D      |....
..+-------+------\-+............+------------+....
..| [When A1=1    \|............| [+] A4     |....
..|  A2 references \............+------------+....
..|  table B]      |............|    ...     |....
..+----------------+............+------------+....
..................................................
```

Note, that a U.M.L. "comment" or U.M.L. "constraint" can indirectly indicate,
what you try to achieve.

Since, this forum its more related to programming, than just diagram, a related c-style program could be something like

```
struct A
{
  int A1;    
  int A2;
  int A3;
  int A4;

  char FirstName[150];
  char LastName[150];

  // other fields
};

struct B
{
  int A2;    

  // other fields
};

struct C
{
  int A3;    

  // other fields
};

struct D
{
  int A4;    

  // other fields
};

int main(...)
{
  int ErrorCode = 0;

  A* RecordA = NULL;
  B* RecordB = NULL;
  C* RecordC = NULL;
  D* RecordD = NULL;

  RecordA = ReadAFromTable();

  switch (RecordA->A1)
  {
    case 1:
      RecordB = ReadBFromTable(RecordA->A2);
    break;

    case 2:
      RecordC = ReadCFromTable(RecordA->A3);
    break;

    case 3:
      RecordD = ReadDFromTable(RecordA->A3);
    break;
  }

  // do other stuff

  return ErrorCode;
}
```

Note, that there are several variations of this, including in modeling & programming, such as having the same keyfield (A1) for all records, instead of different identifiers with same type.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a tool to generate the second graph as you did?

Comment: @user3084213 "http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw" altought sometimes I edited by hand. You may want to mark my response as ok, makuing click in the arrow ;-)